# Join two tables to get matching records alongside with unmatched records

Tags: sql, sql-server

For example I have two tables

```
DECLARE @Employee TABLE( 
   [EmployeeID] INT NOT NULL, 
   [FirstName] VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL, 
   [LastName] VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
   [Value] INT NOT NULL,
   [ExpenditureID] INT NOT NULL
);

DECLARE @Expenditure TABLE( 
   [ExpenditureID] INT NOT NULL, 
   [Type] VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL   
);


INSERT @Expenditure ([ExpenditureID], [Type])
VALUES (1, N'Salary' ),
(2, N'Bonus')

INSERT @Employee([EmployeeID], [FirstName], [LastName], [Value], [ExpenditureID]) 
VALUES (1, N'Orlando', N'Gee', 1500, 1 ),
(2, N'Keith', N'Harris', 1000, 1),
(3, N'Keith', N'Harris', 700, 2),
(4, N'Donna', N'Carreras',2000, 1 ),
(5, N'Janet', N'Gates', 900, 1 )
```

I want to get result like this

```
FirstName | LastName | Value | Type
-----------------------------------
Orlando     Gee        0       Bonus
Orlando     Gee        1500    Salary
Keith       Harris     700     Bonus
Keith       Harris     1000    Salary
Donna       Carreras   0       Bonus
Donna       Carreras   2000    Salary
Janet       Gates      0       Bonus
Janet       Gates      900     Salary
```

I wrote query which returns same result

```
SELECT p.FirstName, p.LastName, SUM(p.Value) AS Value, p.Type FROM (
    SELECT emp.EmployeeID, emp.FirstName, emp.LastName, emp.Value, exp.Type FROM @Employee AS emp
        INNER JOIN @Expenditure AS exp ON exp.ExpenditureID = emp.ExpenditureID 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT emp.EmployeeID, emp.FirstName, emp.LastName, 0, exp.Type FROM @Employee AS emp
        CROSS JOIN @Expenditure AS exp
    WHERE exp.ExpenditureID <> emp.ExpenditureID
) AS p
GROUP BY p.FirstName, p.LastName, p.Type
```

But I don't like this. Is there another solution to get result with more efficiently?

Comment: You have a very poor naming convention.  A table called `employee` should have one row per employee.  Your data model (as shown here) should have three tables:  `employees`, `expenditures`, and `employeeExpenditures`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff there are already created tables, in which there are a lot of records. I have not created it. I want to know to get result in this scenario

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `cross join` to generate the rows and a `left join` to bring in the values:

```
select n.*, e.type, coalesce(em.value, 0) as value
from (select distinct firstname, lastname from employee) n cross join
     expenditure e left join
     employee em
     on em.firstname = n.firstname and em.lastname = n.lastname and
        em.ExpenditureID = e.ExpenditureID;
```

Aggregation does not seem necessary but might be if you have multiple rows that need to be s summed together.  Your sample data has no such examples.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=321f85d976e8aacfbbc50ac867639eff) is a db<>fiddle.